# MySQL - Nested where conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table, which is as follows:

```
 image_id   imagename   brandname    x       y    
    143     00003.jpg     Pirelli  147      265
    125     00003.jpg     Pirelli  500      259
```

Through mouse clicks I am generating x and y positions on a html canvas which I want to use to subset the table.  For example, if the clicked position of x and y were 510 and 262, I want to retrieve the image id 125 as both the parameters are matching.

Suppose if the x value generated with mouse click is 510, i want to select the line with image_id 125.

I tried the following:

```
select * from table where imagename='00003.jpg' and 510 < max(x);
```

I am getting this error:

> invalid use of group function.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Max is a group function... You can't use it without having group by in it.

You are comparing X and y value so use them directly, no need for using  `Max`

Answer (score 0):

As @user769889 already mentioned, you can't use aggregate functions like `Min, Max` etc without using `Group By` that's why you are getting that error.

I think you need this :

```
select * from table where imagename='00003.jpg' and x < 510 and y < 262
```

Answer (score 0):

`Max` is a grouping function, you cannot use it like that. You can achieve what you need by using the followind nested query:

```
select * from table where imagename='00003.jpg' and 510 < (select max(x) from table where imagename = '00003.jpg')
```

This will run the inner query that gives back the maximum value for the `x` column for the image, then runs the outer query using the result in its `where` clause!

Comment: I am getting both the rows returned...instead I have to retrieve only the second line in the table....whereas to test if max(x) condition is working, when I ran the max(x) part of the code separately, it fetches correct result.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
select * from annotations where imagename='00003.jpg' x <= 510 order by x desc limit 1;
```